# Why doesn't QLPreviewController work in SwiftUI TabView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, qlpreviewcontroller

I cannot find a way to get QuickLook(QLPreviewController) to load a pdf inside of a SwiftUI TabView. Is there a way to make this work? It is specifically when I tell Tabview to be a .page View.

```
struct QuickLookView: View {
    @State private var url: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample-PDF", withExtension: "pdf")!
    @State private var tab: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView(selection: $tab) {
                ForEach(0..<3) { num in
                    PreviewController(url: url).tag(num)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct PreviewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> QLPreviewController {
        let controller = QLPreviewController()
        controller.dataSource = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(
        _ uiViewController: QLPreviewController, context: Context) {}
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, QLPreviewControllerDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
        
        let parent: PreviewController
        
        init(parent: PreviewController) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
        
        func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
            return parent.url as NSURL
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very curious. It works when you wrap your PreviewController in a NavigationStack like this:

```
struct QuickLookView: View {
    @State private var url: URL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample-PDF", withExtension: "pdf")!
    @State private var tab: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $tab) {
            ForEach(0..<3) { num in
                NavigationStack {
                    PreviewController(url: url)
                }   .tag(num)
            }
            
        }   .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if you then add a NavigationStack to contain the TabView it stops working again. I hope someone else can shed some more light on this weird behaviour. You may want to file a bug at Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is surprising. If the tab view style is [`.page`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle/page) it does not work, but [`.automatic`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle/automatic) does.

Two possible work-arounds for a paged view of previews jumps out at me:

1. You could eliminate the `TabView` altogether, and just have a `QLPreviewController` (obviously `UIViewControllerRepresentable`) with a data source whose count is greater than 1.  That gives you a UI where you can swipe between previews. No `TabView` with a hidden page indicator is needed.
2. I was wondering if the problem was `QLPreviewController` inside `UIPageViewController`, but that works in UIKit. So you mighty consider doing that, and making the `UIPageViewController` (with its `QLPreviewController` children) the `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.